# My iOS app loses all animation effects when running app sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sqlite, nsdocumentdirectory

I have navigationController based application, and it stores many images in documents directory folder (`[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]`). I have also used sqlite.db for storing images locally. My image storing process is as following:

- My web service returns array of images(url path)
- I convert url image to data and store converted image data to documents directory folder
- image path also saved in my sqlite db.

My problem is when I insert multiple images to documents folder, then my all animation effects stops or loses. Another issue is saving image url to data(`NSData`)is time taking process (my view freezes sometimes). How to solve this issue?please go through following code

> ```
>  //My viewController class
>      NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
>      NSMutableArray * mMsgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
>     for (int i=0; i<[imageArray count]; i++) 
>    {
>         Messages *msg = [[Messages alloc]init];
>         NSSting *imgeUrlPath = [[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@“imgPath”]];
>         NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@“imgPath”]]];
>         msg.msgLocalPath =    [self saveImage:data withFileName:[self getCurrentDateTimeAsNSString] ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];
>         [mMsgArray addObject:msg];
>     }
>     BOOL msgsuccess = NO;
>     msgsuccess = [[DataBaseManager getInstance]saveMessage:mMsgArray];
>     if (msgsuccess == NO) {
>         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message insertion failed" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
>         [alert show];
>     }
> ```

```
 //getting different imageName
-(NSString*)getCurrentDateTimeAsNSString
{
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *retStr = [format stringFromDate:now];
    return retStr;
}
//Saving image to documents path
-(NSString*)saveImage:(NSData *)dataImage withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {

        NSString *localImgpath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]];
        [dataImage writeToFile:localImgpath atomically:YES];
        return localImgpath;
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [dataImage writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
    return nil;
}
```

>

```
//DataBaseManager Class(Insert message local path to sqlite db)    
-(BOOL)saveMessage:(NSMutableArray*)MsgArray;
{

    BOOL insertSuccess=NO;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];//14
    sqlite3_stmt    *mstatement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        for (int i=0;i<[MsgArray count];i++)
        {

            Messages *Msg = [MsgArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into MESSAGES(msg_local_path) VALUES(\"%@\")",Msg.msgLocalPath];
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &mstatement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK){

                insertSuccess = NO;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add a statement parameter to a query.
                if (sqlite3_step(mstatement) == SQLITE_DONE)

                {
                    NSLog(@"SQLITE_DONE");
                    //  sqlite3_reset(mstatement);
                    insertSuccess = YES;
                }
                else   
                {
                    NSLog(@"SQLITE_FAIL");
                    NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    sqlite3_reset(mstatement);
                    insertSuccess = NO;
                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else{
        insertSuccess = NO;
    }
    return insertSuccess;
}
```

Comment: This is some bad formatting. Please format it properly for better readability.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer,can you check my code?

Comment: There are multiple questions in your post. Firstly, `NSData` conversions are time consuming, and should be moved to another thread. Secondly, the animations issue, in most cases, is due to the fact that you are trying to perform UI changes from a thread other than the main thread. Please read [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) and the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: All said, I would like to suggest you to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for asynchronous loading and saving of images. It does most of your work for you. You only need to keep the URLs of images in local storage, and request SDWebImage to get the images for you. Once downloaded, it will automatically cache the images for you. Minimal effort.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer,thank you..how to apply nsdata conversion on another thread?Can u give example with my above code?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer,is image saving in documents folder good or bad for my ios app??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66306/discussion-between-n00bprogrammer-and-user).